# ¿Cómo se envían mensajes con RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: javascript, html5

Hace tiempo descubrí que RTCPeerConnection puede hacer una conexión peer to peer, así que hice esto:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<script>
name=prompt("Enter your nickname.")
net=new RTCPeerConnection()
net.onmessage=function(e){e.data}
net.send(alert(name+" has connected."))
</script>
</body>
```

Sin embargo, no funciona, da el siguiente error:

> TypeError: net.send is not a function

Entonces, cambié el código:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<script>
name=prompt("Enter your nickname.")
net=new RTCPeerConnection()
net.onmessage=function(e){e.data}
net.postMessage(alert(name+" has connected."))
</script>
</body>
```

Y da el siguiente error:

> net.postMessage is not a function

¿Cómo se envía un mensaje con RTCPeerConnection? No me quedó muy claro...

Comment: Necesitas un medio de transporte. RTC funciona enviando flujo de datos, audio y video luego que una conexión ha sido **negociada**. Para que esa negociación ocurra puedes usar [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup), [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), [socket.io](http://socket.io/) o similares.

Comment: Imposible, ninguna de las 3 funciona...

Comment: Estoy seguro que en internet te puedes encontrar varios ejemplos funcionando con cualquiera de las tres variantes.

Comment: Pon alguno si estás tan seguro.

Answer (score 1):

Uff… al parecer estás salteándote mucho. Primero tenés que crear la conexión con `new RTCPeerConnection()`, y luego crear el canal (con `cnx.createDataChannel("sendChannel")`, o esperarlo (con `ondatachannel`).

La siguiente es una adaptación de [un ejemplo de Mozilla](https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel/):

```js
(function()
 {
  var controles=
       {
        btConectar:null,
        btDesconec:null,
        btEnviar:  null,
        bxChat:    null,
        inMsg:     null,
       },
      cnxLocal=null,
      canLocal=null,
      cnxRemota=null,
      canRemoto=null;

  var conectar=function()
   {
//        console.log('conectar');
    // Conexión local:
    cnxLocal=new RTCPeerConnection();
    canLocal=cnxLocal.createDataChannel("sendChannel");
    canLocal.onopen=eventosLocal;
    canLocal.onclose=eventosLocal;

    // Conexión remota:
    cnxRemota=new RTCPeerConnection();
    cnxRemota.ondatachannel=recibir;

    // Agregar candidatos
    cnxLocal.onicecandidate = e => !e.candidate
        || cnxRemota.addIceCandidate(e.candidate)
        .catch(errorCandidato);

    cnxRemota.onicecandidate = e => !e.candidate
        || cnxLocal.addIceCandidate(e.candidate)
        .catch(errorCandidato);
     
    // Recién ahora conecta:
    cnxLocal.createOffer()
    .then(offer => cnxLocal.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .then(() => cnxRemota.setRemoteDescription(cnxLocal.localDescription))
    .then(() => cnxRemota.createAnswer())
    .then(answer => cnxRemota.setLocalDescription(answer))
    .then(() => cnxLocal.setRemoteDescription(cnxRemota.localDescription))
    .catch(errorConectar);
   };
  var desconec=function()
   {
//        console.log('desconectar');
    // Cierra los canales
    canLocal.close();
    canRemoto.close();
    // Cierra las conexiones
    cnxLocal.close();
    cnxRemoto.close();
   };
  var enviar=function()
   {
//        console.log('enviar');
    var msg=inMsg.value;
    canLocal.send(msg);
    /** \todo Guardar mensaje en historial. **/
    inMsg.value='';
    inMsg.focus();
   };
  var eventosLocal=function()
   {
//        console.log('evento');
    if (canLocal)
     {
      var abierto = "open"===canLocal.readyState;
      inMsg.disabled      = !abierto;
      inMsg.disabled      = !abierto;
      if(!abierto)        inMsg.focus();
      btEnviar.disabled   = !abierto;
      btDesconec.disabled = !abierto;
      btConectar.disabled   = abierto;
     }
   };
  var eventosRemoto=function()
   {
/*
    if(canRemoto)
     console.log('El estado del canal de recepción (remoto) cambió a '+canRemoto.readyState);
    else
     console.log('Se disparó un evento de cambio de estado de canal de recepción (remoto), pero no existe.');
*/
   };
  var errorCandidato=function()
   {
    alert/*console.log*/("Hubo un error al crear un candidato… :'(");
   };
  var errorConectar=function()
   {
    alert/*console.log*/('Error al conectar, imposible crear oferta: '+error.toString());
   }
  var iniciar=function()
   {
    for(var ctrlId in controles)
     if(!(controles[ctrlId]=document.getElementById(ctrlId)))
      {
       alert('Error: No se encontró el elemento '+ctrlId);
       return false;
      }
    controles.btConectar.addEventListener('click', conectar, false);
    controles.btDesconec.addEventListener('click', desconec, false);
    controles.btEnviar.addEventListener('click', enviar, false);
   };
  var recibeMsg=function(e)
   {
    var el =document.createElement('li'),
        txt=document.createTextNode(e.data);

    el.appendChild(txt);
    bxChat.appendChild(el);
   };
  var recibir=function(e)
   {
    canRemoto = e.channel;
    canRemoto.onmessage = recibeMsg;
    canRemoto.onopen    = eventosRemoto;
    canRemoto.onclose   = eventosRemoto;
   };

  iniciar();
 })();
```

```css
div {display:block}
.BtDer {float: right;}
.BtIzq {float: left;}
.BxChat {background:#fff;border: 1px solid #000;clear:both;height:15em;margin:0;padding:1em;width:15em;overflow:auto;list-style-type:none}
.BxCnx {background:#ccc;border:1px solid #ccc;clear:both;height: 1em;margin:0;padding: 1em;width: 15em}
.BxMsg {background:#ccc;border: 1px solid #ccc;clear:both;height:2em;margin:0;padding:0.5em;width: 16em}
#btEnviar {width:5em}
#inMsg {width:10em}
#inMsg:disabled:focus {background:#c88;border:1px solid red}
#inMsg:enabled {background:#ccccff;border:1px solid #ccccff}
#inMsg:enabled:focus {border-color:blue}
```

```html
<div class="bxCnx">
 <button id="btConectar" name="btConectar" class="BtIzq">Conectar</button>
 <button id="btDesconec" name="btDesconec" class="BtDer" disabled>Desconectar</button>
</div>
<ul id="bxChat" class="BxChat"></ul>
<div class="BxMsg">
 <input type="text" name="inMsg" id="inMsg" placeholder="Ingresar el mensaje a enviar…" inputmode="latin" disabled>
 <button id="btEnviar" name="btEnviar" class="BtDer" disabled>Enviar</button>
</div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/js/adapter.js"></script>
```

**EDITADO**: Saqué enviar a consola, porque SO hace que tape el ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarme el código completo?

Comment: El código completo es el que está. Ahí anulé algunas salidas por consola para que puedas probarlo en vivo con el botón "Ejecutar". ;)

Comment: Cuando lo envía uno no lo recibe otro...

Comment: @TatoBroh A mí me funciona perfecto el código. Posiblemente sea un problema del navegador, o del sistema operativo.

Comment: Solo con que no funcione en una compu basta para que no sea un chat válido.

Comment: ¿Entonces WhatsApp Web no es un chat válido porque no corre en una 286? RTC es nuevo, todavía no está del todo soportado. Si no funciona, fijate qué error tira en la consola para ver si hay un problema de código, de incompatibilidad, etc.

Comment: winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats?callback=winterBashCurrentHats21782&userids=21782&host=es.stackoverflow.com&_=1483465591958:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats21782 is not defined
    at winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats?callback=winterBashCurrentHats21782&userids=21782&host=es.stackoverflow.com&_=1483465591958:1
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/js/adapter.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 51,
  "colno": 18
}

Comment: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: cnxRemoto is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 86,
  "colno": 5
}

Comment: Eso es, casi seguro, porque tu webbrowser no implementa RTC (que es una tecnología muy nueva y todavía en desarrollo). Si es Chrome podés probar `webkitRTCPeerConnection`, si es Firefox `mozRTCPeerConnection`.

Comment: No lo hacen. En ambos las ventanas permanecen aisladas entre sí.